# Estimating variance of data with a non-response bias

Tags: variance, survey-weights

I have a set of scores whose mean is shifted by a non-response bias and whose variance is reduced as a result of the same bias. I know how to improve the estimate of the mean using non-response weights but how do I improve the variance estimate? More information:
I'm monitoring human disturbance to wetlands, trying to establish a baseline level of disturbance. To monitor a wetland needs permission from land owner. Owners of less intensely used areas more likely give permission than those with wetlands in more intensely used areas. Because intensity of use is correlated with the response variable, there is a non-response bias - our data underestimate the average disturbance to wetlands. Non-response weights can correct for the bias. But our data also underestimate the variance in amount of disturbance. How to get a more realistic estimate of population variance?

Comment: Can you say more about your study, your data, & your goals? This isn't very clear.

Comment: Monitoring human disturbance to wetlands, trying to establish a baseline level of disturbance. To monitor a wetland needs permission from land owner. Owners of less intensely used areas more likely give permission than those with wetlands in more intensely used areas. Because intensity of use is correlated with the response variable, there is a non-response bias - our data underestimate the average disturbance to wetlands. Non-response weights can correct for the bias. But our data also underestimate the variance in amount of disturbance. How to get a more realistic estimate of pop. variance?

Comment: That helps a lot. Can you edit that into the body of your question so that it's more salient than in a comment?